# How to use insertId with big query streaming insert for each rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to use insertId with  Bigquery streaming insert for each row by node.js

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// Inserts data into a table
await big query
  .dataset(datasetId)
  .table(tableId)
  .insert(rows);
console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`);
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO. Have you read this? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency

Answer (score 3):

This feature is poorly documented in the [Node.js docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/RowQueue.html#insert) (by which I mean *undocumented* ). However, there is an example in the unit tests for the Node.js library [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/a138347855f74d4e5c889dc42b00992c4a3808a6/test/table.ts#L2194) and [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/a138347855f74d4e5c889dc42b00992c4a3808a6/test/table.ts#L2515).

The part I had to dig into the unit tests to find was `{raw: true}`.

Here is a full working example:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

const rows = [
  {
    insertId: 'my_insert_id',
    json: {foo: 'bar', baz: 'bax'}
  }
];

await bigquery
  .dataset('my_dataset')
  .table('my_table')
  .insert(rows, {raw: true});
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, unfortunately, the docs are as you described. That is why I kindly ask you if you can give me a hint when and why to use `raw: true` (even in cases without an `insertId`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The insertId is included on the InsertionRow [structure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll#insertionrow), which is:

```
{
  "insertId": string,
  "json": {
    object
  }
}
```

There is a nodejs example [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#insert), but basically:

```
const rows = [
{
  insertId: '1',
  json: {
    INSTNM: 'Motion Picture Institute of Michigan',
    CITY: 'Troy',
    STABBR: 'MI'
  }
},
//...
];
```

As mentioned on the [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) Graham shared:

> To help ensure data consistency, you can supply insertId for each
>   inserted row. BigQuery uses the insertId property to de-duplicate your
>   data on a best effort basis.